# How to write pash scripts for nupkg?

Tags: linux, powershell, nuget

1. How does `nuget` call `pash`? How does it know which shell to run? Should it be the default shell of the current user? How to redefine this?
2. What are the default path conventions for scripts within .nupkg(s)?
3. Which cmdlets should be present by default in `pash`?

Comment: https://github.com/gentoo/dotnet/issues/169

Answer (score 2):

The only support that is available for running PowerShell scripts in MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio requires a [separate addin](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/06/22/NuGetPowerShellConsoleForXamarinStudio/) to be installed.

This provides a PowerShell console and allows PowerShell scripts to run if they are included in a NuGet package. It uses Pash behind the scenes. There are limitations due to the fact that Pash is not feature complete so some PowerShell scripts may fail to run.

1. nuget on the command line does not call Pash. Even on Windows nuget on the command line does not support PowerShell scripts.
2. The conventions for PowerShell scripts in NuGet packages is the same for Pash.
3. You would need to run pash or look at the source code to see what cmdlets are provided.